# file open dotnet core 2.1 System.IO.IOException

Tags: c#, .net-core, dot

I'm creating a dotnet core 2.1 project when I try to open a file I get this error System.IO.IOException because it looks for the file under netcoreapp2.1

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       string path = "C:\user\name\desktop\file.txt";
       FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
   }
}
```

and error is

```
   System.IO.IOException: The syntax of the file name, directory or volume is incorrect C:\Users\name\source\repos\app\app\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\‪C:\user\name\Desktop\file.txt
```

Comment: Please can you provide a [mcve].

Comment: @John this is enough for you to understand my problem if you want more, tell me what

Comment: @John try this 2 row in your VS in an simple console app dotnet core

Comment: This gives me a _compiler error_. Using an absolute path in 2.1 works just fine for me. This is why I ask for a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Because slashes are not escaped, FileStream is assuming the path to be relative to the current folder.
Use literal string or escape the path.

```
string path = @"C:\user\name\desktop\file.txt"; // Note the @ that denotes a literal string.
FileStream file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: This is not the issue. As it stands the code in the question doesn't build, so it can't be exhibiting the behaviour which OP mentions.